# How do Treemaps handle collisions in java?

Tags: java, treemap

Hashmap allows collisions if two objects share an index. How do treemaps handle collisions in java?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a collision? A properly-designed comparator should not encounter a collision, except for a truly-equal key (in which case the two equal keys *should* refer to the same mapping).

Comment: What do you exactly mean by collision? Same result for hashCode?